How to retrieve the full thread of IMAP email message when querying the Inbox?
Using Mailkits (superb) IMAP Api's I need to get the full thread of a message, but when reading the Inbox label I only get the Reply. Here's my small test case...
Initial message sent from Instigators gmail AC to Recipients gmail AC, this is the flow as I see it:

Instigator TX email
Recipient RX email & has Inbox Label
Recipient replies
Instigator RX the reply & has the in Inbox label

The issue is when reading the Instigators Inbox via IMAP (code below) the thread only contains the Reply email NOT the instigators initial email (GMail on chrome shows the full thread so I assume is using AllMail, but we only get the reply when reading Inbox via IMAP)
This is ok for GMail as I can use its AllMail & cache it BUT it is totally reliant on the providers (ie MS Outlook, Yahoo, Zoho etc...) having an AllMail folder implementation and I'm not sure if they all do.
Can anyone confirm this, does IMAP require providers to have an AllMail folder?
Outlook appears not to have the AllMail folder in its web ui implementation but maybe its hidden??
If some providers do NOT have the AllMail folder then will querying the Inbox return the full thread like AllMail does? If not what strategy do we use to get the full thread?
var items =
    MessageSummaryItems.Annotations |
    //MessageSummaryItems.Body |
    //MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure |
    MessageSummaryItems.Envelope |
    MessageSummaryItems.Flags |
    MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate |
    MessageSummaryItems.Size |
    MessageSummaryItems.ModSeq |
    MessageSummaryItems.References |
    MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId |
    MessageSummaryItems.EmailId |
    MessageSummaryItems.ThreadId |
    MessageSummaryItems.GMailMessageId |
    MessageSummaryItems.GMailThreadId |
    MessageSummaryItems.GMailLabels |
    MessageSummaryItems.Headers |
    MessageSummaryItems.PreviewText |
    MessageSummaryItems.SaveDate
    ;

var orderBy_ReverseDate = new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseDate };


// All Mail
//
IList<IMessageSummary> all_summaries_unordered = new List<IMessageSummary>();
IList<MessageThread> all_threads = new List<MessageThread>();

if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.SpecialUse))
{
    var all = client.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.All);
    await all.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    all_summaries_unordered = await all.FetchAsync(0, -1, items);
    all_threads = MessageThreader.Thread(all_summaries_unordered, ThreadingAlgorithm.References, orderBy_ReverseDate);
}

// Inbox
//
// Get Summaries - they contain Envelope, References, Flags (eg Seen),
var inbox_folder = await client.GetFolderAsync("inbox");// TODO:  What is All Mail for Outlook, Yahoo & other providers???
await inbox_folder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
var inbox_summaries_unordered = await inbox_folder.FetchAsync(0, -1, items);
var inbox_summaries = MessageThreader.Thread(inbox_summaries_unordered, ThreadingAlgorithm.References, orderBy_ReverseDate);



The AllMail+Labels is a pure google thing. All others should simply have folders to navigate or have other unique behaviors somehow mapped onto IMAP. Outlook is a client not an IMAP Server? You meant MS365 or Exchange stuff? Then no there isn't something like that. But those might have their own unique crude internal behaviors also because IMAP isn't the prefered protocol there. That would be EWS or rather Graph by now.  Don't expect IMAP to work exactly the same everywhere even if its a standard.

Thanks, yeah I was going to call it hotmail but I think its outlook now but yeah you're right the exchange stuff. So im left with creating an implementation for each provider, that sucks.

Generally you look in the Sent or equivalent folder….

If you really want to thread messages that span across folders (usually Inbox & Sent, for example), the only universal solution is to cache message summary information for all folders locally and then splice together the message summaries from the folder the user is looking at (e.g. Inbox) and the Sent folder, then use the MailKit.MessageThreader utility class to thread those messages.
Once you get a result, then you'll want to strip out threads that only contain messages from the Sent folder.
